# app/views/physicians/show.html.erb:47: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1.Not to sure why i am getting the error fairly new to this. Trying to make a table withing the show page.
2.This is the error i keep getting: app/views/physicians/show.html.erb:47: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'

```
    <p>
       <strong>Name:</strong>
       <%= @physician.name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Specialty:</strong>
      <%= @physician.specialty %>
    </p>

    <h1>Office Locations</h1>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Street address</th>
          <th>Zip</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th colspan="3"></th>
       </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @physician,office_locations.each do |office_location| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= office_location.street_address %></td>
            <td><%= office_location.zip %></td>
            <td><%= office_location.phone %></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <br>



    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_physician_path(@physician) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', physicians_path %>
```

Comment: You have a comma here: `@physician,office_locations`

Comment: Which will lead to the next error.. no end for the do block

Comment: @Mark - good catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax needs to be changed to below for this area

```
 <tbody>
    <% @physician.office_locations.each do |office_location| %> <-- fix this line
      <tr>
        <td><%= office_location.street_address %></td>
        <td><%= office_location.zip %></td>
        <td>
    <% end %> <-- add this
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you!! :) such a simple mistake

Comment: Just one thing that may help going forward, anytime I see an error that says something like `was expecting ...` I usually assume I missed putting a close to something, and almost always that is it.